# Managing side-effects with multiple RxJava Observables

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java, rx-android, rxandroidble

I'm working with a BLE GATT service that has two characteristics that work in tandem.  One is a write-only characteristic where you can submit a string value as a query and the other is a notify-only characteristic where you receive the response to the query.

The notification service is a little slow and it is important not to move on to the next query before the notification is read -- otherwise the response is lost.

To this end, I've been using RxAndroidBle Observables, with separate channels for the write and notify characteristics.  A third Observable provides the queries.  However, the writes have been going far too quickly.

```
ConnectableObservable notifyObservable =
    createNotifyObservable(NOTIFY_UUID).publish();

queryObserverable
    .doOnSubscribe(notifyObservable::connect)
    .doOnNext(query -> Log.d(TAG, "Processing query: " + query))
    .flatMap(query -> createWriteObservable(WRITE_UUID, query)))
    .doOnNext(request -> Log.d(TAG, "Write initiated."))
    .flatMap(request -> notifyObservable)
    .doOnNext(response -> Log.d(TAG, "Query response: " + response));
```

So on running the application, here's what I see in the logs (included are timestamp, process id and thread id):

```
06-22 14:30:01.991 14085-15360 Processing query: Query1
06-22 14:30:02.011 14085-15360 Processing query: Query2
06-22 14:30:02.011 14085-15360 Processing query: Query3
06-22 14:30:07.261 14085-15443 Write initiated.
06-22 14:30:07.301 14085-15445 Write initiated
06-22 14:30:07.321 14085-15447 Query response: Response3
06-22 14:30:07.321 14085-15449 Write initiated.
06-22 14:30:07.321 14085-15447 Query response: Response3
06-22 14:30:07.351 14085-15453 Query response: Response3
```

Is there a way with RxJava to ensure that the next write only occurs after the response is received?

EDIT:
On specifying the suggested `maxConnection` argument to both `flatMap` calls, the calls occur in the proper order, but only for the first query from the Observable.  Here's the log for this case:

```
06-22 14:39:09.841 22245-23079 Processing query: Query1
06-22 14:39:15.131 22245-23166 Write initiated.
06-22 14:39:15.201 22245-23169 Query response: Response1
```

Comment: Can you include the thread id for each log line?

Comment: Ok, I've added more details from the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass maxConcurrent = 1 argument to your flatMap calls:

```
...
.flatMap(query -> createWriteObservable(WRITE_UUID, query), 1)
...
.flatMap(request -> createNotifyObservable(NOTIFY_UUID), 1)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `maxConcurrent` argument.  This met with partial success, where everything is called in the correct order.  This problem now is that only the first query from the Observable is evaluated.

Comment: How does your output look now?

Comment: I've added the log output to the question.

Comment: Could it be that your notifyObservable emits only one item? Try temporarily replacing it with something like Observable.just(1) inside the 2nd flatMap. Will it get stuck in this case?

Comment: Yep, it's still getting stuck in that case.

Comment: In this case there might be a backpressure issue with your source observable: Try replacing queryObservable with Observable.just("Query1","Query2","Query3")

Comment: Same result with replacing queryObservable.

Comment: Thats odd. Try to isolate the issue. For example, here is the equivalent code that works for me.      

Observable.just("Query1","Query2","Query3")

    .doOnNext(query -> System.out.println("Processing query: " + query))

    .flatMap(query -> Observable.just(query).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), 1)

    .doOnNext(request -> System.out.println("Write initiated."))

    .flatMap(request -> Observable.just(request).delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), 1)

    .doOnNext(response -> System.out.println("Query response: " + response))

    .subscribe();

 Thread.sleep(10000);

Answer (score 1):

If there is exactly one response for each query then you could pack your queries in a function:

```
Observable<String> query(String query) {
  return notifyObservable.flatMap(notifyBytesObservable -> // to be sure that when we will start writing we're already listening
    Observable.combineLatest( // with combineLatest both Observables will be subscribed at the same time
      notifyBytesObservable.first(), // to unsubscribe from notification after the first one
      createWriteObservable(uuid, query), 
      { notificationBytes, writtenBytes -> notificationBytes }
    )
  )
    .map(notificationBytes -> String(notificationBytes))
}
```

And now you should be able to make calls like this:

```
queryObserverable
  .flatMap(queryString -> query(queryString), 1)
```

I hope this helps you.

Best Regards